# Write in WPF TextBox without focusing

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, .net-4.8

I am trying to let the user type into a textbox **without my application getting the focus**. The Windows Clipboard History App demonstrates this behaviour (under the GIF tab).

Currently I am making my application show inactive and registering a global hook. Then ia am passing the keychars to the Textbox.
The problem is: Global hooks dont work when an **application running as admin** is in the foreground. The windows clipboard app **does not have this problem**. How can this be achieved?

Comment: basically what you are trying to do is a keylogger. There are many examples on how to create this with c# on github

Comment: these hooks usually use SetWindowsHookEx which i mentioned: do not work if the foreground window is running as admin. the windows clipboard history is working in that scenario